# How to toggle gmaps.js setContextMenu content in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, contextmenu, gmaps.js

I am working on google-map api using [gmaps.js](https://hpneo.dev/gmaps/). I have a problem with google map's [setcontextmenu](https://hpneo.dev/gmaps/examples/context_menu.html).

When the user right-clicks the map, the context menu will appear. I tried to change the content of context menu option from "measure distance" to "stop measure distance".

Below is the code when the user right-clicks, it displays two menus: "measure distance" and "stop measuring". I want to toggle between the two. When the user clicks "measure distance" menu, I want the "measure distance" menu to disappear and the "stop measuring" menu to appear.

How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated so much.

I tried to put flag variable inside the contextmenu but it just didn't work.

```
map_2.setContextMenu({
 control: 'map',
 options: [
  {
   title: 'Measure Distance',
   name: 'measure_distance',
   action: function(e) {
    // some codes here
   }
  },
  {
   title: 'Stop Measuring',
   name: 'stop_measure_distance',
   action: function(e) {
    // some codes here
   }
  }
 ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why isn't the flag variable solution working for you? I just tried coding this real quick and it is working on my end, please test the below code:

```
<script>
    var map;
    var flag = true;

    function initMap() {
        map = new GMaps({
            div: '#map',
            lat: -12.043333,
            lng: -77.028333
        });

        toggle();
    }

    function toggle() {
        if (map) {
            if (flag) {
                map.setContextMenu({
                    control: 'map',
                    options: [{
                        title: 'Measure Distance',
                        name: 'measure_distance',
                        action: function(e) {
                            flag = false;
                            toggle();
                        }
                    }]
                });
            }
            else {
                map.setContextMenu({
                    control: 'map',
                    options: [{
                        title: 'Stop Measuring',
                        name: 'stop_measure_distance',
                        action: function(e) {
                            flag = true;
                            toggle();
                        }
                    }]
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: My mistake was putting flag inside setContextMenu. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! :)